# Replace a particular string in a column with strings in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder how to replace the string value of 'Singapore' in location1 column with the string values from location2 column. In this case, they're `Tokyo, Boston, Toronto` and `Hong Kong, Boston`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'location1':["London, Paris", "Singapore", "London, New York", "Singapore", "Boston"], 
        'location2':["London, Paris", "Tokyo, Boston, Toronto", "London, New York", "Hong Kong, Boston", "Boston"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

          location1               location2
0     London, Paris           London, Paris
1         Singapore  Tokyo, Boston, Toronto
2  London, New York        London, New York
3         Singapore       Hong Kong, Boston
4            Boston                  Boston
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, use `.loc` and indexing:

```
df.loc[df['location1'].eq('Singapore'), 'location1'] = df['location2']
print(df)

# Output:
                location1               location2
0           London, Paris           London, Paris
1  Tokyo, Boston, Toronto  Tokyo, Boston, Toronto
2        London, New York        London, New York
3       Hong Kong, Boston       Hong Kong, Boston
4                  Boston                  Boston
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it using the [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method :

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df["location1"] = np.where(df["location1"] == 'Singapore', df["location2"], df["location1"])
>>> df
    location1               location2
0   London, Paris           London, Paris
1   Tokyo, Boston, Toronto  Tokyo, Boston, Toronto
2   London, New York        London, New York
3   Hong Kong, Boston       Hong Kong, Boston
4   Boston                  Boston
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['location1'] = df['location1'].mask(df['location1'] == 'Singapore')\
                                 .fillna(df['location2'])
```

Output:

```
                location1               location2
0           London, Paris           London, Paris
1  Tokyo, Boston, Toronto  Tokyo, Boston, Toronto
2        London, New York        London, New York
3       Hong Kong, Boston       Hong Kong, Boston
4                  Boston                  Boston
```